# Bake From Multires

Tags: multiresolution

Followed 4 different tutorials. Seem to have closely the same steps

1. Multi-res On Mesh
2. Add New Details
3. Cycles Renderer
4. (Shading Tab) Add New Texture
5. New Image> Color Space: Non-Colour
6. Render Properties Tab
7. Bake: Bake From Multres

I have the the multi-res at levl 6, on test Monkey. Adding test brush marks, big bumps etc.
When I Click bake. I get output but it's just a flat purple UV, no details.
Not many settings tbh.

curretly, Bake Type: Normals, Margin: 16 px, clear image ticked.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to **lower the *Levels Viewport* value in the *Multi Res* modifier settings.**

When you bake a *Normal* map from the *Multi Res* modifier, the *Viewport* levels are basically your low-poly mesh while the *Render* levels define your high-poly mesh. The baked normal map is the difference of both levels.

When you select *Levels Viewport* = `0` and *Render* = `4` for example, it should do the trick.

---

(I have no idea what the *□ Bake from Multires* checkbox in the *Cycles > Bake* settings exactly does. You don't need to check it but you can. If you don't activate it then just select *Normal* for *Bake Type*.

When it's checked it also requires a lower viewport level to work. It seems it automatically selects *Normal* for the *Bake Type*, and hides a few other settings such as the *Influence* and the *Active to Selected* sections. The bake process also seems to be a bit faster and the result differs slightly.

The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html) says only:
**Bake from Multires** - Bake directly from multires object.)

Comment: Thank you. as simple as lowering the viewport display too 0.